# PHP sorting array by numeric Key

Tags: php

I am attempting to sort an array using PHP and want it to be from highest to lowest value using its key. the key came from a PHP query which was pushed using `intval`.

```
do{

   //other operations above..

    $average[] = intval(round($spec['volume']));

}while(odbc_fetch_row($re));
```

Now I have a function to count every occurrence of a value.

```
function array_count_values_of($array) {
    krsort($array);
    $counts = array_count_values($array);

    print_r($counts);
}
```

I used `krsort($array)` which as per documentation.

> Sort an associative array in ascending order, according to the key:

Now here is my output.

```
Array ( [101] => 1 [103] => 5 [106] => 10 [104] => 4 [108] => 10 [105] => 8 [102] => 2 [113] => 12 [107] => 12 [110] => 12 [115] => 16 [112] => 9 [118] => 3 [114] => 7 [111] => 8 [98] => 1 [109] => 10 [123] => 1 [116] => 8 [117] => 2 [99] => 1 [125] => 2 [121] => 1 [135] => 1 [124] => 2 [120] => 1 )
```

Its weird because at first look its ok but when the key value is `108` it returns `105` again. any suggestion would be great!

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @Bhavin My expected output is sorted by key 101,103,105,106,108,113...

Comment: you should sort `$counts`, not `$array`

Comment: What documentation is that? `krsort()` sorts descending, you want `ksort()` to sort ascending

Comment: @KarstenKoop wow I missed that thanks, i got it now i should use `ksort()` now.

Comment: You want to sort by key then don't sort `$array` because it will sort `value`. Sort `$counts` it will sort `key`.

Comment: you are not using ksort properly